# Faulty TCC solenoid or bad computer?

Tags: automatic-transmission, pontiac, p0420, p0122

```
Make:   Pontiac
Model:  Sunfire
Year:   2001
Engine: 2.2 L
Trans:  Automatic
```

Hello to every one, bought my first car and it is fine except for this little annoying problem. After driving it for a while the `trac off` light goes on and the RPMs start to go really high 3K ~ 4K, the transmission does not upshift gears and when it does it kicks a bit hard and I've noticed that if I let go the accelerator the car sometimes shuts down,  this problem comes and goes, it goes away if I stop using the car for a while but eventually comes back, I had the car scanned at autozone and at a transmission repair shop they obtained the following codes:

```
P0122 - Throttle Position Sensor
P0420 - Catalyst System Efficiency Below Threshold
P0742 - Torque Converter Clutch
```

I have a few questions regarding the codes:

- How serious are these codes?
- How reliable is the diagnosis of the scan?
- Which of these are DIY'able?
- What's the recomended order to fix them?

Thank you for all your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to let everyone know that I replaced the TPS and the tracc off problem disapared, I'm only left with the catalyst code.